# Rewrite rule not working, issue may be in URI request

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule so that posts can be accessed both at the default https://example.com/section1/slug and at https://example.com/prefix/section2/slug. The code below is what I have so far. It extracts the slug from the address, uses the slug to get the post ID, and puts the slug and ID into the final rule.

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {
  $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $slug = basename($path);
  $url = 'https://example.com/section1/' . $slug;
  $post_id = url_to_postid($url);
  add_rewrite_rule('^prefix/section2/' . $slug, 'index.php?p=' . $post_id, 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rule');
```

When I echo the variables, they are all correct, but when I run the rule, the second URL format gets a 404 error. The problem seems to be related to `$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. When I supply `$path` manually, the rule works.

Comment: The rewrite rules are meant to create a pattern that is dynamical. I is stored in the rewrite rules array and it is not efficient to add constant post id's to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^prefix/section/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)?', 'index.php?section=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&post_type=post', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rule');
```

Add a query var for section:

```
function my_query_vars( $vars ) {
   $vars[] = 'section';
   return $vars;
}
add_action( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

I created the pattern for your section (which can be 1 or 2) and used $matches[2] to set the "name" parameter, which is your slug. Then I set the "post_type" to "post" to be sure WordPress is searching for a post.

Because I added the query var you can then do:

```
$section = get_query_var( 'section' );
```

To know which section is loaded.

Comment: I think a broader issue for me has been learning the query vars. "Name" obviously would have helped me a lot if I'd known about it. Do you know if there's a resource with their definitions anywhere?

Comment: Maybe you can checkout this codex page? https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars Else you can always ask me for help :)